# Get/Set Data to UI-Objects from BackgroundWorker-Thread

Tags: c#, user-interface, backgroundworker

latly i've been struggeling with getting and setting data from/to UI-Objects. 
I know it's possible to do this from a BackgroundWorker-Thread, by using Invoking. Sadly i've only find on invoking method and it worked fine for setting labels and a bunch of other stuff, but it failed when it came to DataGridViews, Combo- and TextBoxes. This is the invoking "code" i'm talking about:

```
this.uiObject.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
{
    this.uiObject.Text = "Hello World";//Setting Label Text from BackgroundWorker
});
```

As i said i tried using this on the following code, but it didn't work.

```
private void loadPlaylists()
{
    this.playlistGrid.Rows.Clear();//Invoke on a DataGridView

    string filePath = this.genrePath + this.sortBox.SelectedItem.ToString() + ".txt";
    if (File.Exists(filePath) && File.ReadAllText(filePath) != "")
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            bool first = false;
            string line = "";
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (first && line != "")
                {
                    string[] split = line.Split(new string[] { " // " }, StringSplitOptions.None);

                    FullPlaylist playList = spotify.GetPlaylist(split[1], split[0]);

                    this.playlistGrid.Rows.Add(playList.Name, playList.Owner.Id);//Invoke on a DataGridView
                }
                if (line != "")
                    first = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

private void loadItems(bool newItem = false, bool deletedItem = false, string name = "")
{
    this.sortBox.Items.Clear();//Invoke on a ComboBox

    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(this.genrePath);
    foreach (var file in dir.GetFiles("*.txt"))
    {
        string[] split = file.Name.Split(new string[] { ".txt" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        this.sortBox.Items.Add(split[0]);//Invoke on a ComboBox
    }

    if (newItem)
    {
        this.sortBox.SelectedItem = name;//Invoke on a ComboBox
        this.mode = 5;
    }

    if (deletedItem)
    {
        if (this.sortBox.Items.Count > 0)//Invoke on a ComboBox
        {
            this.sortBox.SelectedIndex = 0;//Invoke on a ComboBox
            this.mode = 5;
        }
        else
            this.playlistGrid.Rows.Clear();//Invoke on a DataGirdView
    }
}

private void addPlaylists()
{
    string[] split;
    string filePath = "";
    if (this.sortBox.SelectedIndex != -1)//Invoke on a ComboBox
    {
        filePath = this.genrePath + this.sortBox.SelectedItem.ToString() + ".txt";//Invoke on a ComboBox
    }
    else
    {
        MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Select a valid Category first!",
            "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return;
    }
    if (this.playlistLink.Text != "" && this.playlistLink.Text.Contains("/"))//Invoke on a TextBox
    {
        if (this.playlistLink.Text.Contains("|"))//Invoke on a TextBox
        {
            split = this.playlistLink.Text.Split('|');//Invoke on a TextBox
        }
        else
        {
            split = new string[1];
            split[0] = this.playlistLink.Text;//Invoke on a TextBox
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < split.Length; j++)
        {
            string[] split2 = split[j].Split('/');
            string id = split2[split2.Length - 1], owner = split2[split2.Length - 3];
            FullPlaylist playlist = this.spotify.GetPlaylist(owner, id);
            string write = id + " // " + owner + " // " + playlist.Name;
            this.changeOrAddLine(filePath, write, write);
        }

        this.playlistLink.Text = "";//Invoke on a TextBox

        this.loadPlaylists();//Call to a Methode, where Invoke is needed
    }
    else if (!this.playlistLink.Text.Contains("/"))//Invoke on a TextBox
    {
        //Error
        this.playlistLink.Text = "";//Invoke on a TextBox
    }
    else
    {
        //Error
    }
}
```

Those are the three methods i'm calling from the BackgrounddWorker. The code is fine and works outside of the BackgroundWorker. I marked all Lines where Invoking(if it's even needed) should be used, because there it's doing something with an UI-Project. I hope someone of you guys is able to show me how to do this. I'm not expecting you to take my code and add the fixes, just a overall example on how to do this should work aswell. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Anywhere you affect a UI control, wrap that logic in an invoke call.  So for instance, rather than:

```
this.playlistGrid.Rows.Clear(); // No
```

Do this:

```
uiObject.Invoke(() => this.playlistGrid.Rows.Clear()); // Yes
```

This effectively sends a message to the UI thread to perform that operation when the time is right in the UI's message loop.  If you wrap every interaction with your UI controls in an invoke like this, the errors should cease, but beware tht you are blocking the background thread while you wait for the result of the Invoke.  Be sure the UI thread doesn't in-turn wait for the background thread or you'll have deadlock.  You can avoid this by using BeginInvoke but you do need to **be aware of the fact that the operation may not happen immediately**.  For instance, if you wish to read something from a control, **not** do this:

```
string localValue = null;
uiObject.BeginInvoke(() => { localValue = this.sortBox.SelectedItem.ToString(); });
// should NOT assume you can use localValue here
```

You generally are better off gathering all data from your controls in your UI layer before invoking your async action and passing it to the background process.  For example:

```
private void loadPlaylists(string selectedItem)
```

Comment: but "this.playlistGrid.Invoke(() => this.playlistGrid.Rows.Clear());" gives an error.

Comment: **"Lambda expression" can not be converted to the "Delegate" type because it is not a delegate type.** (roughly translated from german into english)

Comment: If that doesn't work, you can try: `.Invoke((Action)(() => ...))`.  Invoke was created in a bygone era of .NET where lambdas didn't exist, so they tried to make it "easy" to call different delegate signatures.